# Singing a C# over a F chord

Tags: harmony

I'm writing a song and suddenly I noticed I'm singing a C♯ over an F major chord. It sounds good (I suppose), but I'm a bit worried about the tension.

I know it's common to sing the minor third over a major chord, but here I'm in between the fifth and the sixth of the F major scale.

This is occurring over a very simple progression: B♭ - E♭ - F - B♭. The style can be said to be blues and/or maybe a bit jazzy...

Any thoughts?

Comment: What's the context of that chord? What's the chord progression around it?

Comment: I'm voting "needs details" because with no context, any number of reasons as to why this (subjectively) sounds good exist.

Comment: What kind of genre are we dealing with? Those are notes from the F/A augmented scale, they would sound "good" in jazz/blues.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. It is a very simple progression: Bb Eb F Bb.

Comment: It can be said that is a blues, a bit jazzy maybe...

Comment: If it's C#, it'll be jazz. If it's Db, it'll be Blues...

Comment: of course the chords are important, but where does the `C#` go next?

Answer (score 1):

Given your progression, it seems like it could be an F augmented leading to the B♭ rather than just F. F+ is F A C♯. That C♯ leads nicely to the M3 of B♭ (D), while the A of the F+ leads chromatically the same way (up) from A to B♭.(As far as the harmony is concerned).

Answer (score 0):

Given the note progressions you provide (F-A-C-C# and B♭-E♭-F-B♭), I would argue that your piece is in either of those:

- B♭ melodic minor: B♭ C D♭(C#) E♭ F G A (ascending) | B♭ C D♭(C#) E♭ F G♭ A♭ (descending)
- B♭ harmonic minor: B♭ C D♭(C#) E♭ F G♭ A

As opposed to F major. Both scales are good for jazz and blues (I would recommend harmonic minor personally, but that's a matter of taste). It is unclear whether the entire work is in B♭ or if you're just modulating to it for a single section following the Circle of Fourths (because F is followed by B♭ on the Circle).

Comment: If this is the true explanation, then the note the OP has called C# is in fact D♭. We'd need more context to be sure which is true.

Comment: @RosieF, I agree. I have used sharps and flats "freely" ("conventionally") as they would normally be used (to my knowledge) in a piece with no predefined accidentals (sharps for C, F and G; flats for A, E and B). Given I am providing examples of specific scales, they should indeed be more uniform. Thank you for noticing.